# Meteor public folder not working

Tags: meteor

I'm new to Meteor and I'm trying to understand how to serve static content - images, JS, etc.. I've followed the docs by creating the correct folder structure (which it doesn't really touch on) but making requests to this content just fails over to serving the main app page instead.

For instance - putting an image in "app_root"/public/image.png and making a request to localhost:3000/image.png just returns the main app page.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: After running "meteor", can you look inside app_root/.meteor/build/static/ and see if your image appears there? Also, what is the actual name of your file? Is it actually image.png?

Answer (score 19):

The setup you have described sounds correct to me. Media in `public/` are served like

```
http://localhost:3000/myphoto.jpg
```

The todos example serves images from the public directory. Just back out of whatever project you're in and run: `meteor create --example todos` then cd into todos/ and run `meteor`.  Then open:

```
http://localhost:3000/destroy.png
```

The image you will see lives in `public/`.

Answer (score 16):

> Meteor public folder not working

Use `./public` directory for serving static assets.

Given the following directory structure:

```
- server
- client
- public
  - css
    - bootstrap.css
  - images
  - js
```

You could serve the static assets by dropping 'public' from linked documents.

`<link href='/css/bootstrap.css'>`

More info here: [Official Meteor Docs #FileStructure](https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/filestructure)

> Files in /public are served to the client as-is. Use this to store
>   assets such as images. For example, if you have an image located at
>   /public/background.png, you can include it in your HTML with  or in your CSS with background-image:
>   url(/background.png). Note that /public is not part of the image URL.

Comment: what happen to css folder, does that work under public ?

Comment: in this example, youd want to drop `public` from the url

Answer (score 2):

That same thing happened when I moved the project files in a folder and forget to move the directory .meteor.