# Meteor package, how to add static files

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm creating a package and, for the client side, I need to add some static files like fonts and images. After trying some *outdated* solution I found nothing seemed to work for me. How should I add those files? Create a public folder inside my package? Adding the files with `api.addFiles`?
Is this even possible?

Comment: excellent question, have you raised an issue to get this documented ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### update: meteor 1.2

You should now use [api.addAssets](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/PackageAPI-addAssets) to add static files to your package.

---

### original answer

You can add static assets to any package and they will be served by meteor. The easiest way to demonstrate this is with an example. Have a look at the source for [hopscotch](https://github.com/Dsyko/meteor-hopscotch).

The package contains an `img` directory with the file `sprite-green-0.3.png`. If you look at the `package.js` file you can see that it gets added to the client with:

```js
api.addFiles('img/sprite-green-0.3.png', 'client');
```

After adding the package to your project, you can access the file directly with this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/packages/hopscotch/img/sprite-green-0.3.png
```

In summary, you can use [api.addFiles](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_addFiles) to add static assets. All assets will be accessable under a path like `/packages/[package name]/[path to asset]`.

Note that you can add `{isAsset: true}` as a third argument to `addFiles` for assets which should not be automatically loaded. [This post](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/get-text) contains an example of its use.

Comment: You should use `{isAsset: true}` for CSS and JS files that you don't want auto-loaded on the client.

Comment: If your package has a name with a ":" in it (as most username-namespaced packages do now) it gets translated to an underscore. An image living in "public/img/sprite.png" in "author:packagename" will be found at "/packages/author_packagename/public/img/sprite.png".

Comment: @user85461 thank you so much, this is what we were missing.  I wish this were better documented, it's funny how this small comment was the missing link.

Comment: nice, this iis a pretty important feature actually and I'm disapointed at how long it took us to find this answer, thank you so much!

Comment: is there a way to pass the list of assets from the package.json into the package code itself? You often define which assets to add in the package.json but then need to run through a loop to load them inside runtime code.

Answer (score 0):

For assets file like favicon.ico or fonts files you can create a `public` folder.

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11589366/3479609) or the [documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories).