# Meteor packages with images

Tags: meteor

I want to create a theme package with css, js and images. The theme package looks like:

```
packages/
  theme
    css
      theme.css
    js
      theme.js
    img
      logo.png
```

I can package css and js like so:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  var themeFiles = [
    'theme/css/theme.css',
    'theme/js/theme.js'
  ];

  api.addFiles(themeFiles, 'client');
});
```

Do I need to package the images to use them? I tried to ref the logo png like this but it didn't work:

```
<a href="/packages/theme/img/logo.png">logo</a>
```

How can non css or js files can be distributed and used as meteor packages?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare package assets such as images using the regular `api.addFiles` method :

```
api.addFiles("img/logo.png","client",{
  isAsset: true
});
```

`isAsset` is not mandatory here because we're adding an image, but note that if we wanted to add JS or CSS files as public staticly served files, we would have to specify this option to avoid Meteor bundling these files along with the concatenated/minified initial app JS/CSS.

Then you will be able to reference these assets using this type of path :

```
`/packages/package-author_package-name/img/logo.png`
```

Given that your package name is `package-author:package-name`.

Comment: Thanks but how do you know this? It is not in the docs. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_addFiles

Comment: This is the kind of advanced use you can learn by reading a lot of resources in the Meteor community and sometimes reading the project source code, which is open BTW. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/b61d10618d5c5e51bb3a94adbcf0e635a4d4dce3/tools/package-api.js#L289

Comment: This question is also relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143504/meteor-package-how-to-add-static-files. Especially the package name (author name) is important. In my case it will be 'packages/myusername_theme/img/logo.png'

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `api.addAssets(filenames, architecture)` and access from client like  `/packages/username_package-name/file-name` see https://docs.meteor.com/api/packagejs.html#PackageAPI-addAssets