# Add static file in a private meteor package

Tags: meteor, static, package

How can I add a static file like a simple picture to a **private** meteor package? Can't find any further information.

[Meteor package, how to add static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143504/meteor-package-how-to-add-static-files) is not working for me and I don't know why.

Meteor with Ironrouter is used.

**Update from comment:**

If I create a private package (e. g. author:package) and I try to add a static file by calling

```
api.addFiles([ 'lib/client/picture.png' ], ['client']);
```

I can't reach this source via

```
localhost:3000/packages/author_package/lib/client/picture.png
```

Instead of the picture I see a Ironrouter message "route does not exist".

Comment: what do you mean by "is not working for me"? It's hard to help you if all you are saying is that the way the documentation tells you to do it isn't working.

Comment: If I create a private package (e. g. author:package) and I try to add a static file by calling api.addFiles([ 'lib/client/picture.png' ], ['client']); I can't reach this source via http://localhost:3000/packages/author_package/lib/client/picture.png. Instead of the picture I see a Ironrouter message "route does not exist".

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed a private package, i.e., one that only resides in your project's packages folder and was added to meteor using `meteor add package` (rather than `meteor add author:package` like you would for atmosphere packages), then the url should be:

```
localhost:3000/packages/package/lib/client/picture.png
```

i.e., without the `author_`.

Answer (score -2):

You're using the `addFiles` api wrong. `api.addFiles('img/picture.png', 'client');` there are no arrays used in the call http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_addFiles

Also, make sure you list your package in the `packages` file under `/.meteor`

Comment: that is not true, the documentation clearly states and gives examples of the use of arrays in `addFiles`.

Comment: @ChristianFritz there is only one file in the question so using an array is redundant. taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143504/meteor-package-how-to-add-static-files

Comment: I agree that it is unnecessary to use an array, but it's not a problem either and in particular it is not the cause of the problem the OP is experiencing.